# Access crosstab query number sorting issue

Tags: sorting, ms-access, crosstab

I have this query that is used as the Row Source for A Chart

[image]

If i do a Round on the [nom_trykk] i get the expected sorting, but the problem is Access replaces , with _ and the chart cant then read the values as it is expecting numbers.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(([dig_avl_st] - Eval("Forms!gv!avgk")) / Eval("Forms!gv!avgk") * 100) AS [K-Factor]

SELECT "Error from" & Chr(13) & "average" AS Expr1
  FROM T_måledata AS M
   WHERE (((M.Sertifikat_Nr) = 163194))
     GROUP BY "Error from" & Chr(13) & "average"
     ORDER BY Round([nom_trykk], 1)
PIVOT Round([nom_trykk], 1);
```

[image]

So my thinking was to try and format the numbers with FORMAT.

[image]

but then Access interprets the values as string and the sorting brakes and messes up the flow chart.

[image]

[image]

Have anyone worked trough this problem before and know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to format with leading zeroes:

```
Format([nom_trykk], "0000.0")
```

and, as *comma* can't be used:

```
Replace(Format([nom_trykk], "0000.0"), ",", "_")
```

Note, that Format will also do the rounding.

Comment: Thank you @Gustav. I had tryed with "0,0" but that gave me same result,,, but after reading your reply i tryed with leading zeroes so "0000,0" and its working as i want :) saved me alot of work.